# How to write a truly secure user profile with zero identifying information, that they can do password resets to?

Tags: javascript, security, identity, software-design

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to build a user profile system on a site that is so secure that there's absolutely no way to figure out that person's identity; while also allowing them to reset their password?

- Don't want their email
- Don't want a phone number for SMS
- Don't want to use the social media platforms to authenticate
- Cannot use secret questions because they forget their own answers
- Cannot use a TOTP app on a cell phone because people lose/break their phones (and some still don't have a cellphone)
- Cannot use a cookie on their device because it isn't universal across phone/laptop/tablet, and they break their devices
- Cannot fingerprint their browser agent, ip, etc, because the users access the site from multiple systems, from multiple different IP's.  There are also multiple users logging in from the same home computer.
- Cannot issue them a physical token because cost, and, they'd lose them

Has anyone figured out an identity broker system that isn't associated with big social media?  The user could register their identity stuff with the 3rd-party broker, and the broker just gives me a key to identify them?  That is free for everyone to use?  Kind of like the GPG key ecosystem...

Looking for ideas.  How can I register an account for you, but no matter how hard I try, I never have any data that I could use to Google you?

Comment: So you want someone to be able to reset their password, but have no email or phone number associated with their account? Where to they click to reset their password? Do they have a username? Is the username secret too?

Comment: Reminds me a bit of https://en.gravatar.com/

Comment: The logical trick in the question is you saying that there should be no way to figure out their identity, because they don't want to provide their email, phone and so on. Yet a third party identity provider is ok. But not Facebook, Facebook is not ok. :) From there, it's just a question of which 3rd party you trust and which you do not trust, and I don't think it's possible for us to answer that.